# How can I execute a JS index in RavenDB?

Tags: node.js, ravendb

I want to use an index and saw this:

```
class Products_ByCategoryName_JS extends AbstractJavaScriptIndexCreationTask {
    constructor () {
        super();

        const { load } = this.mapUtils();

        this.map("Products", product => {
            return {
                // Call method 'load' to load the related Category document
                // The document ID to load is specified by 'product.Category'
                // The Name field from the related Category document will be indexed                
                categoryName: load(product.Category, "Categories").Name

                // Since NoTracking was Not specified,
                // then any change to either Products or Categories will trigger reindexing
            };
        });
    }
}
```

and this is how I execute the query

```
const matchingProducts = await session
    .query({indexName: "Products/ByCategoryName"})
    .whereEquals("CategoryName", "Beverages")
    .all();
```

its from the docs, ok but how can I execute the index Class above Products_ByCategoryName_JS,

so where it is executed or where can I included it in my code ?

€: got this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Map is required to generate an index, you cannot create an index without a valid Map property (in index Users/ByName)
```

index:

```
// @ts-nocheck
import { AbstractJavaScriptIndexCreationTask } from "ravendb";

export class Users_ByName extends AbstractJavaScriptIndexCreationTask<{name: string}[]> {
  constructor () {
      super();

      this.map = `
        from users in docs.UsersData
        select new {
            Name = users.name
        }`;
  }
}
```

query:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await new Users_ByName().execute(store);
    let session = store.openSession();
    const queryOnIndex = session.query({indexName: 'UsersData/ByName'}).whereEquals('name', 'Johnse');

    const d = await queryOnIndex.all();
    res.json('s');
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.send(e);
  }
});
```

what I am doing wrong ?
My collectionName is UsersData and my field name is "name" that I want to index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute/deploy the index to the server, call:

```
await new Products_ByCategoryName_JS().execute(documentStore);
```

---

See **demo "static indexes overview"** in the Node.js client:
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/nodejs/static-indexes/static-indexes-overview
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/nodejs/static-indexes/static-indexes-overview#step-3

---

In the latest example you provided - the index class name is: `Users_ByName`, but in the query, you use index name: `UsersData/ByName`.

In the query you should use the index name from the 'class' and only replace `_` with `/`. 
So, in your query you should use: `session.query({indexName: 'Users/ByName'})`

---

More info about **creating and deploying** indexes is available in:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/latest/nodejs/indexes/creating-and-deploying 
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/latest/nodejs/indexes/creating-and-deploying#naming-convention

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I got this error: InvalidArgumentException: Map is required to generate an index, you cannot create an index without a valid Map property (in index Users/ByName) , I have edited my code above so you can see what I did

Comment: @lambdamaster In the latest example you provided - the index class name is: `Users_ByName`, but in the query, you use index name: `UsersData/ByName`. In the query you should use the index name from the 'class' and only replace `_` with `/`. So, in your query you should use:  `session.query({indexName: 'Users/ByName'})`